# Why does this SQL works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My colleague puzzled me by a working SQL that I think should actually fail.

- Table `[IdentityUserRoles]`: columns `RoleId`, `UserId`;
- Table `[IdentityRoles]`: columns `Id`, `Name`;

SQL executed that worked:

```
Delete from IdentityUserRoles where RoleId in ( 
   Select RoleId 
   FROM [dbo].[IdentityRoles] 
   where Name in ('TeamManager','Manager')
)
```

It looks legit first, but if you look closely on sub-query, table `IdentityRoles` does not have `RoleId` column, it should be `Id` instead.

So if I run sub-query separately :

```
Select RoleId 
FROM [dbo].[IdentityRoles] 
where Name in ('TeamManager','Manager')
```

I get error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'RoleId'.

Which is as expected, as column `RoleId` indeed does not exist.

The question is, why does parent query goes ahead with execution if the sub-query contains syntax error?

I run this in SQL Server 2012 Express edition (v11.0.5058.0)

**Update**
Making this query work - no problem. The issue was why did it work in the first place and did not throw syntax error.

Comment: Well, if RoleId *isn't* from IdentityRoles, where *is* it coming from? Incorporate this into the title/question.

Comment: This works as specified by the SQL standard: any sub-query has access to all columns from the "parent" query. If a column is not found in the tables from the sub-query the columns from the outer query are used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's true! feel like "duh"! now)

Comment: The delete statement deletes any row from the IdentityUserRoles?

Comment: @miguelbgouveia yes, it blew all the records from `IdentityUserRoles` table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you mind writing out this as an answer, so you can get some virtual currency that can be used nowhere))

Comment: I try that example in SQL Server 2008 R2 and the server return an error in the delete statement. Are you sure you don’t have and RoleId column in the table IdentityRoles? If you have it, it’s very strange the SQL Server behaviour.

Comment: @miguelbgouveia `[IdentityRoles]` does not have `RoleId` - absolutely certain. But `[IdentityUserRoles]` does have this column. And sub-query gets access to parent query table/columns. Hence when sub-query is not run in isolation `RoleId` is taken from parent query. This has been pointed out by guys in comments. Just waiting for them to write up an answer.

Comment: You are right @trailmax, using a column with a name that exists in the main table doesn’t get any error in SQL Server 2008 R2.  It is not an error, just an SQL interpretation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with SQL Server here. This is an expected behaviour!

Mistakenly specifying RoleId in the subquery lead to SQL Server think that its a **Correlated sub query.**

The way SQL Server evaluated this is, it searched for RoleId in IdentityRoles first, it could not be found there, so it searched in IdentityUserRoles table. There it found! So this is a valid query.

However if you expected a different behaviour that of a **self contained sub query**... Add an alias as below.

```
Delete from IdentityUserRoles where RoleId in 
 ( 
   Select r.RoleId FROM [dbo].[IdentityRoles] r where Name in ('TeamManager','Manager')
 )
```

**The above query will fail as SQL Server would search that column explicitly in IdentityRoles table.**

However if some best practices are followed, this unintentional bug would not appear. The best practice (in 99% cases) is to have same column name representing same attribute.

Another thing is, as a practice it is better to follow aliases for joins, subqueries etc and refer to column names with those aliases in selects. This would avoid any such unintended bugs or issues.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Yes, thanks for spelling this out properly. Bad practice indeed. But that was ad-hoc query for one-time clean-up. Promise not to do that again! -)